# Python - Creating a dictionary using List

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the below strings in a list and have been able to create a dictionary using the list as key in the dictionary and assigning default of ''. When I print, I see the dictionary is created in reverse order for string in list. Why does this happen and how to correct it. Is there a reverse syntax required ?

```
a = ['hello','bye','tc','iam']
created_dict = dict((bl,'') for bl in a)
print created_dict # {'iam': '', 'bye': '', 'hello': '', 'tc': ''}
```

What needs to be changed to get the below result.

```
expected result : {'hello': '', 'bye': '', 'tc': '', 'iam': ''}
```

It maintains the order when numbers are used in list

Comment: Are you sure you need it to be ordered? If so, a dictionary is not the data structure you want. A list or linkedlist would probably be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular dictionaries in Python have no notion of key order, you need an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
o = OrderedDict.fromkeys(['hello', 'bye', 'tc', 'iam'], '')                    
repr(o)
OrderedDict([('hello', ''), ('bye', ''), ('tc', ''), ('iam', '')])
```

Comment: "you need an OrderedDict" - more likely, order is unnecessary, and using an OrderedDict will just encourage unnecessary headaches about trying to maintain a specific order in the face of dict modifications.