# Python: Creating a dictionary using list comprehension from a list using lambda

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, list-comprehension

Conceptually, here is what I want to do:

```
lookup = {'A': 'aaa', 'B': 'bbb', 'C': 'ccc'}
keys = ['A', 'B', 'Z'] # Note 'Z' does not exist in dict
result = {}
for key in keys:
    if key in lookup:
        result[key] = lookup[key]
    else:
        result[key] = None
```

The above code yields the following, i.e.

```
# result == {'A': 'aaa', 'Z': None, 'B': 'bbb'}
```

Based on the advise in [this post about dictionary comprehension syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python) I am able to do the following using v2.6 syntax:

```
result = dict((lambda x: (x, lookup[x]) if x in lookup else (x, None))(key) for key in keys)
```

Which works and produces same results.

However, I was hoping that I would be able to do the following in v2.7 style (also mentioned in the above post).  But that does not seem to work,

```
result = { (lambda x: x: a_dict[x] if x in a_dict else x: None)(key) for key in a_list }
```

I seem to be running afoul of use of `:` in lambda with that in denoting a key.  I have also reviewed the examples given in the [original PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), too.  They don't provide any guidance, either.  Below is the output from command line:

```
>>> result = { (lambda x: x : a_dict[x] if x in a_dict else x: None)(key) for key in a_list }
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    result = { (lambda x: x : a_dict[x] if x in a_dict else x: None)(key) for key in a_list }
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do, i.e. use v2.7 syntax of dictionary comprehension with lambda?

Please note that I ask this *only* out of curiosity; it's not that I have a compulsion to write such production code, one that would require an expert to understand!

PS: I should mention two other related posts that I found helpful while trying do this.  First is about [using lambda in list comprehension.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076270/python-lambda-function-in-list-comprehensions)  And another is [creating a dictionary using list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061013/python-creating-a-dictionary-using-list).

Answer (score 16):

To do what you are trying with dictionary comprehension, you should make use of [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method. Example -

```
>>> lookup = {'A': 'aaa', 'B': 'bbb', 'C': 'ccc'}
>>> keys = ['A', 'B', 'Z']
>>> result = {key:lookup.get(key) for key in keys}
>>> result
{'Z': None, 'A': 'aaa', 'B': 'bbb'}
```

`dict.get()` returns `None` if the key is not present in the dictionary. You can also specify a second argument to `dict.get()` which would be the default value returned, if the key you are trying to *get* is not present in the dictionary.

---

To answer the question, you cannot use `lambda` to return something like a key:value pair in a dictionary comprehension (since the `:` syntax is not valid). If you want to do that, you should use `dict()` function with a generator expression , Example -

```
result = dict((lambda x: (x,a_dict[x]) if x in a_dict else (x,None))(key) for key in a_list)
```

or the more readable `map()` version -

```
result = dict(map((lambda x: (x,a_dict[x]) if x in a_dict else (x,None)), a_list)
```

Comment: Thanks @Anand this helps.  Both answers obviate the need for me to use lambda. However, the second part of my question does remain unanswered, i.e. is it possible to use lambda while using v2.7 dictionary comprehension syntax.

Comment: @AlokLal Answered your question in the answer, please check it out.

Comment: very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do can be done with a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {k: lookup.get(k) for k in keys}
```

`k` will be the key and `lookup.get(k)` will be the value. `.get()` will get the value of a key from a dictionary or `None` if it is not present. The default value can also be set as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Klaus, it helps.  I posted a follow up on prior answer.