# How to create a dictionary using a single list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of url's and headers from a newspaper site in my country. As a general example:

```py
x = ['URL1','news1','news2','news3','URL2','news1','news2','URL3','news1']
```

Each URL element has a corresponding sequence of 'news' elements, which can differ in length. In the example above, URL1 has 3 corresponding news and URL3 has only one.

Sometimes a URL has no corresponding "news" element:

```py
y = ['URL4','news1','news2','URL5','URL6','news1']
```

I can easily find every URL index and the "news" elements of each URL.

My question is: **Is it possible to transform this list into a dictionary in which the URL element is the key and the "news" elements are a list/tuple-value?**

**Expected Output**

```py
z = {'URL1':('news1', 'news2', 'news3'),
     'URL2':('news1', 'news2'),
     'URL3':('news1'),
     'URL4':('news1', 'news2'),
     'URL5':(),
     'URL6':('news1')}
```

I've seen a similar question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061013/python-creating-a-dictionary-using-list), but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Please include the code you wrote that does not produce the desired output.

Comment: It's possible, but there probably isn't anything particular elegant like `dict(foo(bar(baz(x))))` for some set of functions `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.

Comment: Are you generating `x`? If so, there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm scrapping a web-site using Selenium and i though that using list in this way were easier to work with. But it isn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> y = ['URL4','news1','news2','URL5','URL6','news1']
>>> result = {}
>>> current_url = None
>>> for entry in y:
...     if entry.startswith('URL'):
...         current_url = entry
...         result[current_url] = ()
...     else:
...         result[current_url] += (entry, )
...         
>>> result
{'URL4': ('news1', 'news2'), 'URL5': (), 'URL6': ('news1',)}
```

Comment: You can use `deafultdict(list)` to save at least 4 lines. I'm not sure why you opted to use tuples if you knew you needed to add new items

Comment: @DeepSpace, the OP wanted tuples, so here they are! I was using lists originally but then edited the code to use tuples. As for `defaultdict` - absolutely; I'm always forgetting about it.

Comment: @DeepSpace I see your point about using tuples. I rearranged ForceBru's answer to fit arrays instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a `key` function to identify a URL:

```
from itertools import groupby
def _key(url):
    return url.startswith("URL") #in the body of _key, write code to identify a URL

data = ['URL1','news1','news2','news3','URL2','news1','news2','URL3','news1', 'URL4','news1','news2','URL5','URL6','news1']
new_d = [list(b) for _, b in groupby(data, key=_key)]
grouped = [[new_d[i], tuple(new_d[i+1])] for i in range(0, len(new_d), 2)]
result = dict([i for [*c, a], b in grouped for i in [(i, ()) for i in c]+[(a, b)]])
```

Output:

```
{
 'URL1': ('news1', 'news2', 'news3'), 
 'URL2': ('news1', 'news2'), 
 'URL3': ('news1',), 
 'URL4': ('news1', 'news2'), 
 'URL5': (), 
 'URL6': ('news1',)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the indices of the URL keys in the list and grab what is between the indices and assign to the first

Like this:

```
x = ['URL1','news1','news2','news3','URL2','news1','news2','URL3','news1']
urls = [x.index(y) for y in x if 'URL' in y]
adict = {}
for i in range(0, len(urls)):
    if i == len(urls)-1:
        adict[x[urls[i]]] = x[urls[i]+1:len(x)]
    else:
        adict[x[urls[i]]] = x[urls[i]+1:urls[i+1]]
print(adict)
```

output:

```
{'URL1': ['news1', 'news2', 'news3'], 'URL2': ['news1', 'news2'], 'URL3': ['news1']}
```

Comment: `if 'URL' in y` would also be `True` for a string like `http://mytinyURL.com`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @jjramsey but that's not in his list.

Comment: True, but the items `'news1'`, `'news2'`, etc. are clearly placeholders for items that may contain nearly arbitrary text, including a string containing the characters `'URL'`.

Comment: @jjramsey he can obviously modify it based on his use case. That's like saying this specific code wouldn't work if 'Cat' was one of the URLs-it's arbitrary. the idea is to use the indices and find something unique about the urls to be able to get them.

Comment: @jjramsey I should have pointed out that the ```news``` items don't have ```'URL'``` in them.

Comment: @PedroHenrique you're fine, you already said in your post that you can easily find the indices of the news and url items so that's what I went off of.

Answer (score 3):

The [more-itertools library](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) contains a function [`split_before()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_before) which comes in very handy for this purpose:

```py
{s[0]: tuple(s[1:]) for s in mt.split_before(x, lambda e: e.startswith('URL'))}
```

I think this is cleaner than any of the other approaches in answers posted before this one, but it does introduce an external dependency (unless you reimplement the function), which makes it not appropriate for every situation.

If your actual use case involves real URLs or something else, rather than strings of the form `URL#`, then just replace `lambda e: e.startswith('URL')` with whatever function you can use to select the key elements apart from the value elements.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `groupby`, one-liner:

```
x = ['URL1','news1','news2','news3','URL2','news1','news2','URL3','news1', 'URL4','news1','news2','URL5','URL6','news1']

from itertools import groupby

out = {k: tuple(v) for _, (k, *v) in groupby(x, lambda k, d={'g':0}: (d.update(g=d['g']+1), d['g']) if k.startswith('URL') else (None, d['g']))}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'URL1': ('news1', 'news2', 'news3'),
 'URL2': ('news1', 'news2'),
 'URL3': ('news1',),
 'URL4': ('news1', 'news2'),
 'URL5': (),
 'URL6': ('news1',)}
```